# FancyUpload with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use FancyUpload in a JQuery based project? The page in which I will use FancyUpload is made of JQuery. How to use FancyUpload? Please mention every steps in details. Please

Comment: http://mootools.net/ is required for FancyUpload or you can try to write it with jquery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should use http://www.uploadify.com/demo/, its native Jquery with Flash. FancyUpload is a mootools plugin.

Comment: I have had a lot of issues with uploadify.  Files larger than 100Megs just crashed out.  For smaller files it works well though.

Answer (score 7):

You could just place jQuery in noConflict mode.  Doing this requires that you put wrappers around all jQuery code where mootools will be loaded on the page.  It's simple enough.

Example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// Example with Sep Mootools and jQuery domready's...
(function($){
  window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    // Do some MooTools Magic here!
  });
})(document.id);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Do some jQuery stuff!
  });
})(jQuery);


// Example with Mootools used as domready, with jQuery calls inside
(function($){
  window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    // Some mootools magic here! 
    //......
    //Option 1 for jQuery using jQuery identifier...
    alert(jQuery("#some_input_value").val());

    // Option 2 for jQuery using temp override of $
    (function($) {
      alert($("#some_input_value").val());
    })(jQuery);
  });
})(document.id);
</script>
```

Comment: If you place jQuery in noConflict "mode", you wouldn't necessarily need the wrappers setting "$" to "document.id" for MooTools code, would you?  It seems like you only need to choose one direction, either set jQuery to "noConflict" and wrap only jQuery code, or do not force "noConflict" for jQuery and only wrap MooTools code.  Granted, if you were doing complex mixes of jQuery and MooTools code (like using a jQuery snippet inside a MooTools-wrapped block), then you would need to wrap the jQuery code.  However, it is probably very, very bad practice to do such a thing...

Answer (score 1):

I successfully implemented FancyUpload with jQuery loaded as I discussed above.  jQuery.noConflict() is the best solution if you want both jQuery and Mootools to co-exist.  Otherwise, yeah, probably should stick with either "just" jQuery or "just" mootools.

My opinion, though, is that (while I'm a jQuery fan), the FancyUpload tool for Mootools is hands-down the cleanest, nicest looking, best/easiest to use tool for the job.  it's the only piece that was mootools for me, and is light-weight enough to include without seriously burdening the browser loadtime.

Answer (score 0):

If your heart is set on using FancyUpload in your jQuery project:

Step #1: Get [MooTools](http://mootools.net/).

FancyUpload does not work in jQuery, and as far as I know, there are no plans to make it do so. There are, of course, plenty of alternatives, such as meo's answer, above.